# RPM alternative to dpkg-divert

Tags: rpm, dpkg

I'm trying to port some scripts from Ubuntu to Centos6 (for docker)

Now I'm having trouble trying to replicate this in Centos (which I am not very familiar with)

```
dpkg-divert --local --rename --add /sbin/initctl
```

Comment: heres the **dpkg-divert** man http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=dpkg-divert

Comment: YUM is to RPM what APT is to DPKG ;).

Comment: derp :facepalm: yes I knew that.

Comment: found this. http://rpm5.org/cvs/tktview?tn=5

Comment: I'm guessing by what you found that for now is not possible in a way that isn't complicated...

Comment: @Braiam it was complicated.... theres a lot of ways to solve it too, scrap the entire idea of divert and just install the package as usual, or as simply as setup an alias for it (which actually works out by far the easiest). etc. In my case it was multiple steps depending on need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent tool to this in RPM packaging that I've ever seen. You control where files get installed via the `.spec` file. The only thing you can do at install time is override the prefix.

```
$ sudo rpm --prefix=/home/dir/ some.rpm
```

Comment: That could work. As long as the system will know it's installed and relocated